# Column data as column heading

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, plsqldeveloper

I am facing a very nasty problem to create reports. For this, I would like to have column data as column headers.

Tables:
**skill_table**

```
SKILL_ID    |      NAME
3431060     |      Stomach
3431064     |      Hand
3437806     |      Finger
```

**localnode_table** (which actually has the order/alignment (like what is next and what is previous) of the name from skill table.

```
NODE_ID  |  PREVIOUS_ID  |  NEXT_ID
3431060  |               |  3431064
3431064  |    3431060    |  3437806
3437806  |    3431064
```

How to make it appear like:

```
Stomach |   Hand |   Finger
3431060 |  3431064 | 3437806
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 1):

check out this topic

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

and oracle specific

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1036809

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your requirement,

```
SELECT
     ( SELECT SKILL_ID FROM skill_table WHERE  name = 'Stomach'),
     ( SELECT SKILL_ID FROM skill_table WHERE  name = 'Hand'),
     ( SELECT SKILL_ID FROM skill_table WHERE  name = 'Finger')
FROM dual       
    UNION ALL
SELECT
     ( SELECT NAME FROM skill_table WHERE  name  = 'Stomach'),
     ( SELECT NAME FROM skill_table WHERE  name  = 'Hand'),
     ( SELECT NAME FROM skill_table WHERE  name  = 'Finger')
FROM dual;
```